# Did Galacta ever give birth?

Tags: marvel, comics, continuity, galactus

In the one shot about Galacta (Galactus' 'daughter') it is eventually revealed she is 'pregnant'.

[image]

Does she ever give birth? Does she ever appear again, to resolve this story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell researching this, it was not yet revealed what came out of that pregnancy story.

The Twitter [account](https://twitter.com/#!/Gali_girl) is not active, and there don't seem to have been any more comics with a story line based on my searching marvel.com

P.S. Galacta's story was the result of a contest where budding writers would make Marvel short stories, and the winner would get their own series.